# Why the loop skipped certain actions and proceeded to the next round

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

Problem explained:
I wish to scrape all reviews from this url:

```
https://seedly.sg/reviews/p2p-lending/funding-societies
```

So what I want to do is:

1. use selenium to click all the "more" button if the comments are long
2. get each review
3. click to the next page

But how my code is currently running it is printing:

•   clicking more in another page

•   clicking more in another page

•   clicking more in another page

•   clicking more in another page

•   appended 1 review

•   appended 1 review

•   appended 1 review

•   appended 1 review

•   appended 1 review

•   going to the next page

•   going to the next page

•   going to the next page

which shows that python skipped certain codes. 
There should be "clicking more in another page" & "append 1 review" after " going to the next page"

May I know what causes this problem? How can I solve it?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code

```
'''Loop all pages'''
for i in range(0,3):
    '''Automation of clicking all more'''
    test = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class,"sc-1rz2iis-2 xgYML")]')
    for x in range(0,len(test)):
        more = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class,"sc-1rz2iis-2 xgYML")]')
        more.click()
        sleep(1)
        print("clicking more in another page")
    '''Getting reviews''' 
    reviews = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"sc-1rz2iis-1 iMLmnZ")]')
    for y in reviews:
        reviews = y.text
        reviews_list.append(reviews)
        print("appended 1 review")
    '''Automation of getting to the next page'''
    sleep(4)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/div/div/ul/li[11]').click()
    print("going to the next page")
```

Comment: That's not your full program, right? Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [requests library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for your task *(it will make things substantially faster)*. That said, your code should look something like this

```
import requests


star_rating = []
text_rating = []

for page_nmb in range(1,10000000):
    url = f"https://api.seedly.sg/api/v4/product/items/5/reviews?page={page_nmb}&sort%5Bby%5D=updated_at&sort%5Bdir%5D=desc&include_latest_comment=true&per=100"
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"}
    raw = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    if len(raw["data"]) == 0:
        break
    for review in raw["data"]:
        star_rating.append(review["rating"])
        text_rating.append(review["text"])
```

(`star_rating` has the amount of stars every review left and `text_rating` has all the written reviews left on the page).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I've solved the problem. It's because I didn't add sleep after clicking the next page, so it hasn't fully loaded the page, making me unable to click "more"

Comment: @JoeyWong No worries, glad this helped! If you could accept the answer (click on the grey tick near the answer) that would be awesome! Happy new year!

Comment: Happy new year! Wish you an awesome year ahead!